# Virtual network between host and guest VM (without port forwarding)

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'd like to have a **network** between the **VM host** and the **VM guest**.

The bridge network works for this purpose - but the issue with this is, I'm assuming it'll be limited to the actual physical network's hardware bandwidth (my router in this case).

Is there an implementation of a  "virtual network"? This excludes NAT where you have to set up port mappings.

Comment: i dont understand exactly what you want. Assigning addresses to Contact the VM from host can be done by local lan ips, also it is possible to assign Public IPs to the vm directly. So whats your question now?

Comment: I'd like an network route between the VM host and the VM guest. The only 'direct' network route for this seems to be the "bridge" network - which has the disadvantage of relying on the actual network hardware.

I'm essentially looking for a "virtual network" between host and guest.

Comment: 1) what kind of virtualisiation do you use, proxmox? 2) do you want to nat or route your network? 3)it is possible to have a virtual switch see for like open vswitch

Comment: 1. Virtualbox 2. No NAT 3. Will take a look thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be correct for your environment, but a network connection between the host and the guest should not use the physical network at all.

The guest has it's own MAC address and IP Address.  When the host wants to talk to the guest the network stack on the host needs to lookup the MAC address for the guest's IP and should identify that as being on the bridged connection.  It can then communicate directly with the guest.

You can check this by monitoring the network (from another machine, not the host or one if it's guests) and you should not see any ARP requests issued from the host for guest IP Addresses.

If the network stack is limiting the throughput of the network according to the hardware's capabilities you could try adding an addition internal only network that carries the IP Addresses you use for internal communications.

Comment: Awesome! I'll try test this and confirm - may be a few days though!

Comment: @rob this is true in case that you talk about Private network where no mac Filter is applied. In bigger network this will usually not work due the active filtering. however isolated seen from host to guest its regardless but to the outsite that makes the sifference here

Comment: @Djdomi thanks for your comment. The question is about communicating between a host and a guest - that is a virtual machine running on the host. Not to the outside world (off subnet) or to another physical machine (or a virtual machine on that host).

Comment: then use openv switch this should virtualize your network

Comment: @Djdomi - thank you for your comment but I don't understand how it relates to either the question, my answer, or my comment to your comment ... sorry if I appear to have missed something.